# jQuery ScrollBubble on Scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, bubble-popup

I've a function which shows floating bubble with numbers on scroll. Its running fine and showing bubble on scroll but mostly after scrolling the bubble keeps toggling. Here is the example below please check and assist me where is something wrong in code. And thanks in advance.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPmKLJ

CSS:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}

#scrollbubble {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 98;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#scrollbubble:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -8px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    margin-top: -4px;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.fn.scrollBubble = function() {
    var base = this,
        selector = $(base),
        win = $(window),
        $doc = $(document),
        container = $(base.selector),
        scrollTimer = null;

    if (win.width() > 940) {
        var viewportHeight = win.height(),
            scrollbarHeight = viewportHeight / $doc.height() * viewportHeight,
            progress = win.scrollTop() / ($doc.height() - viewportHeight),
            distance = progress * (viewportHeight - scrollbarHeight) + scrollbarHeight / 2 - container.height() / 2;

        container.css('top', distance).text(Math.round(progress * 100) + '%').fadeIn(100);

        if (scrollTimer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
        }
        scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            container.fadeOut();
        }, 1000);
    }
};
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#scrollbubble').scrollBubble();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="scrollbubble"></div>
```